# Redirect URL in UBER Api App registration form

Tags: android

Can you please explain what needs to be entered to the "REDIRECT URI" section in the Register Application form in the UBER Developer website.

Comment: I have had a look in the Getting Started section. It explains how to use the API but there is no mention of what needs to be put in the Redirect URL field in the registration.

Is this an actual website that I must specify?

Comment: I just put the following in the Redirect URL field... https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize

Is that wrong?

Comment: Frank, I am still not clear on this. I have not used OAuth before, a real newbie to Rest API and also to Oauth. 

Rather than redirecting me back to the Uber blog, could you briefly explain what a typical value for redirect url would be? Is it a real website that I need to specify or is it just an arbitrary url that I can make up, for example  "https://stillconfused.com"?

I have been trying to make sense of the uber site but not any closer to understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The url must be `https://` not `http://` make it like that and it will work fine for a URL of your choosing.